# linux rsync problem

Tags: linux

i following the tutorial of the 
http://www.howtoforge.com/mirror-your-web-site-with-rsync-on-fedora-10
i have completely step by step following the instructions and setup the key, script

my problem is when i use server1 to type the command , it still prompt me for password.

then i look the /var/log/secure, i 've found the message

Authentication tried for root with correct key but not from a permitted host (host=123132132312.static.ctinets.com, ip=20x.80.236.xxx).

can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Either your local machine doesn't know about any ssh key, or the remote machine doesn't trust yours.  Check if ~/.ssh/id_rsa or ~/.ssh/id_dsa exist.  If they do, look at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on the remote machine and make sure that the contents of the file ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub or ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub on the local machine are somewhere in there.

Comment: but i use command>rsync -avz -e "ssh -i /root/rsync/mirror-rsync-key" root@www.domain.com:/home/someone /home/someone ____  /root/rsync/mirror-rsync-key it point to the private key of local machine?

Comment: Is it asking you for the key passphrase or for root's password?  If it's the latter, verify that /root/.ssh/authorized_keys contains the public key that corresponds to the mirror-rsync-key private key.

Comment: one strange thing, sever1 can ping server2, but server2 can't ping server1, may this casue the problem?

Comment: That's not likely the issue at all, no.  If it's asking you for a password it has managed to connect and chat with the other sshd.

Comment: i use mypc use putty to login server1 to type command to rsycn to server2, cause this issue?

Comment: No, that should not cause the issue either.  Are you even listening to my advice?  Check and see if the public key was correctly added to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys on server2.

Comment: i think the /root/.ssh/authorized_keys is placed correctly

Comment: Run the 'ssh' command with '-v' to see what's going wrong.